# Creating a drupal-composer/drupal-project gave me an outdated version of core

Tags: installation, composer

When I ran

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev mysite --no-interaction
```

it installed `drupal/core:8.8.0-alpha1`.  Then to see what was wrong, I ran

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.8.5
```

and the output was

```
drupal/core-dev 8.8.0-alpha1 requires drupal/core (self.version)                             
drupal/core 8.8.5 requires zendframework/zend-diactoros (^1.8)      
drupal-composer/drupal-project dev-master does not require  zendframework/zend-diactoros (but 1.7.2 is installed)
```

What should I do next to get the most recent stable version? 
Was I supposed to run `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal=project:8.8.5`?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of PHP you are using from the CLI?  I just ran the same command w/ PHP 7.4 with an empty composer cache, and couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: Php 7.4.4 I did not clearcache and wil run it again

Comment: running it again produces - still Installing drupal/core-dev (8.8.0-alpha1)

Comment: I redid the way I entered the composer command and used "composer create-project drupal/recommended-project mysite" and it downloaded all of hte code properly and was current. I can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Drupal using this instead: composer create-project Drupal/recommended-project mysite and everything is current and correct.